# SSRS allows to access a secured web service as data source?

Tags: ssrs-2008

Am trying to access a secured XML web service as a data source from SSRS RDL.But its giving an error "Failed to prepare the web request for the specified URL".

Am not sure whether SSRS allows to access a secured web service as data source?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS allows HTTPs with basicHttpBinding. In my wcf service am using wsHttpBinding thats why its failing.Now am using basicHttpBinding to access this as the data source in my SSRS report.